# Orchard CMS - Blog Archive does not follow theme styling

Tags: templates, content-management-system, styles, orchardcms

I added a Blog Archive widget to my [Orchard CMS blog](http://logiczone.me/logically-me/archive/2013/6).  It displayed the archive dates as intended and clicking the date displays a list of blog posts that fall under the date.  The problem I have is with the list of blog posts that are being shown.  They do not seem to follow the regular blog post style.  Looking at the source the posts are simply rendered as plain  tags without any CSS classes.  Using the shape tracing tool tells me that they're simply rendered as the List core shape.  I've tried modifying the Blog Archive content part to add a CSS part, but that didn't work.  I've create several shape alternates using the tracing tool but none of them worked.  Can anyone out there point me to the right direction?  Much appreciated.

Comment: Could you post some pictures and/or code?

Comment: Sorry, I can't post images because I don't have enough reputation points.  However, my question includes a link to my blog which you can see the archive styling renders the <UL> as plain lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, that list should have a class on it. Please file a bug for it. The fix is simple but requires modification of the blog module. In BlogPostController, after the line saying `var list = Shape.List();`, add this:

```
list.Classes.Add("blog-archive");
```

Comment: Thanks, Bertrand.  It appears that there is already a similar issue filed at the Orchard codeplex site (https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/18952).  I applied your fix (actually I added an extra class "content-items"), recompiled the blog DLL, uploaded it to my site, restarted the App Pool and everything is working nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Override ListByarchive View from Orchard.Blogs/Views/BlogPost in your Theme 
in the view instead of line

```
@Display(Model.ContentItems)
```

which renders the archilves list

replace it with

```
@{     
    var blogPosts = Model.ContentItems;
    var items = blogPosts.Items;
}


///write your own logic here
@foreach (var item in items) {
    <div>
            @Display(item) 
    </div>
}
```

you can see live [here](http://bhoopaljanga.azurewebsites.net/blog/archive/2013/8)